# Nightwatchjs - getElementById not working

Tags: javascript, children, nightwatch.js

Ok, so I must be doing really stupid here as I can't get a basic command to work!

So in my nightwatchjs script I want to get the list of values from a drop-down menu option, as below;

[image]

and here is my javascript code;

```
'module.exports = { 
  Search using Make, Model and Price filters': function (browser) {
    var c = browser.getElementById('ddl-make').children;
    console.log(c);
  }
};
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

I get the following error each time;

**✖ TypeError: browser.getElementById is not a function**

(I get the same error if I replace *browser* with *document*, and if I replace the *getElementById* with *getElementByValue*)

Am I doing something obviously wrong with the getElementById command, which is causing this error?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElementById() is not a function that NightwatchJS provides. However it does have an element() function that takes a css selector.

[This is how their documentation describes the element() function:](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/commands/#element)

> Search for an element on the page, starting from the document root. The located element will be returned as a web element JSON object.
>   First argument to be passed is the locator strategy, which is detailed on the WebDriver docs.

Comment: Ok, so as an update to this. When I use the following;    
`this.elements('css selector', '#bfsDesktopFilters .search-filters__item #ddl-make > option', function (result) {
var numberOfElementMakes = (result.value.length);` it correctly lists the total number of elements.  However, it's the text of all the elements that I'm after. Thanks.

Comment: You can loop through the list of children and use console.log on the innerText of the child to get the text.

`c.forEach(child => console.log(child.innerText));` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Milan Karmen, but this wouldn't work for me as **c** is defined as `var c = browser.getElementById('ddl-make').children;` and **nightwathjs** does not support **getElementById**.

Comment: When using .elements() you would have to switch things around a little bit. Give this a try:

`this.elements('css selector', '#bfsDesktopFilters .search-filters__item #ddl-make > option', function (result) {
    result.forEach(child => console.log(child.innerText));
});`

Comment: Ah, this generates a different error. So my code is `'Search using Make': function (browser) {
  browser.elements('css selector', '#bfsDesktopFilters .search-filters__item #ddl-make > option', function (result) {
   result.forEach(child => console.log(child.innerText));
  });
 },` but I now get a **✖ TypeError: result.forEach is not a function** error.

Comment: Could you console.log(result) inside that function and tell me what the contents are? The only reason I could see for this error would be is if result is not an array, but I believe it should be.

Comment: Yeah, the output is; ```Running:  Search using Make
{ sessionId: '82eebc4f5697520d0e9fdc44ca2ae800',
  status: 0,
  value:
   [ { ELEMENT: '0.7136239840107927-1' },
     { ELEMENT: '0.7136239840107927-2' },
     { ELEMENT: '0.7136239840107927-3' },
     { ELEMENT: '0.7136239840107927-4' },
     { ELEMENT: '0.7136239840107927-5' },
     { ELEMENT: '0.7136239840107927-6' },
     { ELEMENT: '0.7136239840107927-7' }...``` (up to all 93 children within the element.

Comment: Okay it looks like nightwatchjs wraps the results instead of giving them directly. So our array of elements isn't just in results, but instead in results.value.

So give this a try, the only difference from before is changing result.forEach to result.value.forEach:

`{ browser.elements('css selector', '#bfsDesktopFilters .search-filters__item #ddl-make > option', function (result) {
    result.value.forEach(child => console.log(child.innerText)); });
}`

Hoping we got it right this time :)

Comment: Thanks for your perseverance in this @MilanKarman :) Well, there's no error message as such now, but the out now reads `Running:  Search using Make
undefined
No assertions ran.` So the element is coming back as **undefined** Thanks

Comment: I think I might have made a wrong assumption about how to get the text from the element. If I'm understanding it right now then the elements() function doesn't return the true element so we'll have to get it otherwise. What I found that we can use the [elementIdText()](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/elementIdText.html) function to get the text from an element which we found using elements().

Comment: Here's what I think that would look like:
`'Search using Make': function (browser) {
    browser.elements('css selector', '#bfsDesktopFilters .search-filters__item #ddl-make > option', function (result) {
        result.forEach(element => {
            browser.elementIdText(element.ELEMENT, function (text) {
                console.log(text);
            });
        });
    }); 
},`

I'm not set up to test this myself so there could be mistakes.

Comment: Yey, this now works! :) `this.elements('css selector', '#bfsDesktopFilters .search-filters__item #ddl-make > option', function (result) {
  result.value.forEach(element => {
   this.elementIdValue(element.ELEMENT, function (text) {
    console.log(text.value);
   });
  });
 });` Many, many thanks for your help in this @Milan Karman, you've saved me a lot of time and effort.